# SYBASE SQL- SET STATEMENT for Turning Off "T-SQL Text Output"?

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

EDIT: Turns out it was a setting in Rapid SQL

I'm using Rapid SQL IDE to produce a report and there's several `T-SQL` steps that create `temp tables` and produce a line in the table grid output that says "The command completed with no results returned." Because of these lines of output, I have to re-run a commented section of the code to produce a clean version of the actual report after the `temp tables` were created. Is there a way to get rid of those `T-SQL` outputs so that I can just run the clean report after the T-SQL steps are done and not have to re-run, using a `SET STATEMENT` like `SET T-SQL-OUTPUT OFF`? I don't see anything in MS's Dev Network (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx)

Sample output:

```
1 | The command completed with no results returned. |
2 | The command completed with no results returned. |
3 | The command completed with no results returned. |
4 | The command completed with no results returned. |
5 | The command completed with no results returned. |
6 | The command completed with no results returned. |


  | Date    | TransType | Customer | Sales |
1 | 1/1/2012|     S     | ABC Co.  | $100  |
2 | 1/1/2012|     S     | ABC Co.  | $200  |
3 | 1/1/2012|     S     | ABC Co.  | $300  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output does not come from T-SQL or the Sybase server. It probably comes from the application.

Comment: So it would probably be a setting in Rapid SQL?